# Database issue with ZF application

Tags: zend-framework

I have a website built on Zend Framework. I want to run the site on my local machine.
I am using wamp server and I created the database for the website.

When loading the site I get the following errors:

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'devhyper_links'@'localhost' (using password: YES)' in E:\wamp\www\hyper\code\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Abstract.php on line 144
( ! ) PDOException: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'devhyper_links'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in E:\wamp\www\hyper\code\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Abstract.php on line 129
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  368952  {main}( )   ..\index.php:0
2   0.0422  1681728 Zend_Application->bootstrap( )  ..\index.php:20
3   0.0422  1681760 Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->bootstrap( )  ..\Application.php:355
4   0.0422  1681760 Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->_bootstrap( ) ..\BootstrapAbstract.php:583
5   0.1858  5863392 Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->_executeResource( )   ..\BootstrapAbstract.php:619
6   0.1858  5863520 MKLib_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap->_initUtf8( ) ..\BootstrapAbstract.php:666
7   0.1970  6299480 Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->exec( )   ..\Bootstrap.php:60
8   0.1970  6299480 Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->getConnection( )  ..\Abstract.php:263
9   0.1970  6299480 Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect( )  ..\Abstract.php:315
10  0.1970  6299480 Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect( )   ..\Mysql.php:96
11  0.1970  6299968 PDO->__construct( ) ..\Abstract.php:129
( ! ) Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'devhyper_links'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in E:\wamp\www\hyper\code\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Abstract.php on line 144
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  368952  {main}( )   ..\index.php:0
2   0.0422  1681728 Zend_Application->bootstrap( )  ..\index.php:20
3   0.0422  1681760 Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->bootstrap( )  ..\Application.php:355
4   0.0422  1681760 Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->_bootstrap( ) ..\BootstrapAbstract.php:583
5   0.1858  5863392 Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->_executeResource( )   ..\BootstrapAbstract.php:619
6   0.1858  5863520 MKLib_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap->_initUtf8( ) ..\BootstrapAbstract.php:666
7   0.1970  6299480 Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->exec( )   ..\Bootstrap.php:60
8   0.1970  6299480 Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->getConnection( )  ..\Abstract.php:263
9   0.1970  6299480 Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect( )  ..\Abstract.php:315
10  0.1970  6299480 Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect( )   ..\Mysql.php:96
```

Comment: This doesn't really solve your problem, but if I were you I wouldn't put an underscore "_" in my database name. It caused me many troubles when I decided to work with Doctrine ORM 1.2 as I tried to generate the models from the database. It has something to do with the way Zend framework interprets the naming conventions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to

1. Create a database user `devhyper_links` on your local MySQL database
2. Grant appropriate privileges for `devhyper_links` to your local MySQL database

Something like

```
GRANT ALL ON db_name.* TO "devhyper_links"@"localhost" IDENTIFIED BY "password";
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Please note that `ALL` privileges may be too open. Customise at your discretion.

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/grant.html#grant-privileges

Comment: yes i created a database user as devhyper_links but the same errors displayed again

Comment: Are you sure you're using the right password in your app? Try connecting to your DB from the command line using the credentials in your app, eg `mysql -u devhyper_links -ppassword db_name`. Also, have you flushed privileges after granting the user access?

Comment: i cant understand your solution

Comment: @user1229903 You've accepted my answer, so what was the actual problem?